# How to create commands to search specific kinds of files using `helm-projectile`?

Tags: search, commands, helm-projectile

I want to be able to search python, typescript, and markdown files separely with [helm-projectile](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html). Is there a way to create distinct keybindings to search the contents of files with each extension.

There is a variable `projectile-globally-ignored-files`. Should I set this for a particular call using [dynamic binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html)

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. E.g., move the question about that variable to another question. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I think that is just one question. The section *There is a variable projectile-globally-ignored-files. Should I set this for a particular call using dynamic binding* is just his first attempt to solve his question.

Comment: @Tobias yep that's correct. In general you can solve all problems with write a bunch of code" but this can sometimes create unnecessary worrk and go against the grain.